# How do I use Onclicklistener to call on press adn hold of button and not on its release as it does so?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

```
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(arg0.getId()){

    case R.id.bFOR:
        try {
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes("b");
            //dataOutputStream.writeBytes("a");
        }catch (UnknownHostException e) {//catch and
            outputText(e.getMessage());//display errors
        } catch (IOException e) {//catch and
            outputText(e.getMessage());//display errors
        }

        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {
            switch (arg0.getId()) {

                case R.id.bFOR:
                    try {
                        dataOutputStream.writeBytes("b");
                        //dataOutputStream.writeBytes("a");
                    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {//catch and
                        outputText(e.getMessage());//display errors
                    } catch (IOException e) {//catch and
                        outputText(e.getMessage());//display errors
                    }

                    break;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: i want to put while statement in it so it keep sending data until another button is pressed. Is there any interrupt call in java?

Comment: You can make for example a global `boolean` value in the activity and set it to `true`, then add it as a condition in the while loop. And then get an `OnClickListener` which will, when the button is pressed, change that global variable to `false`, thus stopping the loop

Answer (score 0):

use setOnLongClickListener, it will make your work